# Broadcast join is failing for 4 GB table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to broadcast a table in a join having 4 Gb size but it is failing with the below error:

```
Cannot broadcast the table that is larger than 8GB: 15 GB
```

The other table is around 5 TB.

My doubt is how the spark framework is broadcasting 15 GB when the data to be broadcasted is only 4 GB.

I am using 15 GB driver memory and 22 GB Executor memory. Number of cores is 5.

Other properties being used:

```
"spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=30",
"spark.driver.maxResultSize=30g",
"spark.executor.memoryOverhead=2g",
"spark.driver.memoryOverhead=3g",
"spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=300",
"spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec=uncompressed"
```